# (Angular) How to return different Observable type request in my case?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am having trouble to return an observable. It seems like the codes inside the mergeMap is not running at all.

Codes:

```
book.service.ts

import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

export class bookService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        ...others
    ) {}

addNewBook(book): Observable<Book>{
    ##### Tried to use mergeMap otherwise the return type won't match
    return this.tokenService.getToken().mergeMap((token: string) => { 
        console.log("Fire this...") <===== This is never output.
        const myUrl = "www.testurl.com";
        const parameters = {
            bookTitle: book.name,
        };

        return this.http.post<Book>(myUrl, book);

    })
}
```

token.service.ts

```
public token$: Subject<string>;

..others

public getToken(): Observable<string> {
    return this.token$; <= return Observable<string> not Observable<Book>
}
```

book.component.ts that calls the addNewBook method.

```
...others
    return Promise.resolve()
         .then(() => {
              return bookService.addNewBook(book);         
         }).then((result) => {
             console.log(result); 
         })
```

I can't really change the token service because it's used on other place, I am not sure why the codes inside the mergeMap is not running. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you will have to subscribe to the observable and execute the mergemap code inside the subscribe block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work unless you subscribe to the results of `bookService.addNewBook(book)`. Just returning it from the `then` callback won't subscribe. You need to at least add `toPromise`.

```ts
...others
    return Promise.resolve()
         .then(() => {
              return bookService.addNewBook(book).toPromise();         
         }).then((result) => {
             console.log(result); 
         })
```

Comment: Thanks it fires the codes inside the addNewBook method but the console.log(result) won't fire anymore.

Comment: Promise completes along with underlying  stream.. Perhaps token$ never completes? How did you get this? Maybe just token$.take(1) is enough.

Comment: It does complete, not sure what happen here.

Comment: It's my other code issue, your theory works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order for the mergeMap() to be be triggered, the token$ subject inside token.service.ts needs to emit a value (via .next()) *after* addNewBook() is subscribed to by a consumer.

One of the things to keep in mind with Subjects is that 'late subscribers' won't receive a value off of them until the next time .next([value]) is called on that Subject. If each subscriber, no matter how late, needs to immediately receive the last value generated by that source (Subject) then you can use BehaviorSubject instead.

From your short code example it is hard to see where the Observable generated by addNewBook() is being subscribed to though. Remember, a Observable won't execute until it has a subscriber.

Comment: Thanks, but if I do this 
return this.tokenService.getToken().subscribe((token: string) => { ...
It will give me error
Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Book>'

Comment: Right, that's because you want to return and Observable from your AddNewBook() function. Subscription would happen at the component level.

Comment: so not sure what other options I still have. :(

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz example?